# Android Fotoapparat library

Tags: android

I'm new to Android-Developement and I would like to make a Camera-app. I found [this](https://lorentzos.com/making-pictures-capture-in-android-simple-74416a19e800) library ([this](https://github.com/RedApparat/Fotoapparat) is the Github page).

But I don't know how to implement a library. I followed [these](https://github.com/MagicMicky/FreemiumLibrary/wiki/Import-the-library-in-Android-Studio) steps (method 2) but I'm getting an error in a popup window called 'IDE Fatal Errors'. It says: 'To investigate / fix the problem IDE wants to attach following files to the bug report. We recommend to include all the files providing maximum information. Note: all the data you send will be kept private.' Then I can select a 'diagnostic.txt'. There is a section 'file content' where 'rootsChanged' is written. I can report the whole window to Google.

The following step is to configure the 'Fotoapparat' instance. What is an instance? When I search on Google I only find articles talking about making a library.

I'm sorry if these are stupid question but I am a beginner and I would like to learn more about Android-Development. Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Comment: Why not start with something simple? You can go to the more advanced stuff after you have the basics under your belt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line in your build.gradle(Module: app) file ->

```
dependecies {

//Your other dependencies...

implementation 'io.fotoapparat:fotoapparat:2.3.3'

}
```

And start using your code. Library is working fine.

**EDIT - >**

You need to learn basics of java.

> To setup instance of the object you need to create a variable.

Hence in your case:

```
Fotoapparat yourVariableName = new FotoapparatFotoapparat
    .with(context)  
    .into(cameraView)           // view which will draw the camera preview
    .previewScaleType(ScaleType.CenterCrop)  // we want the preview to fill the view  
    .photoResolution(ResolutionSelectorsKt.highestResolution())   // we want to have the biggest photo possible
    .lensPosition(LensPositionSelectorsKt.back())       // we want back camera
    .focusMode(SelectorsKt.firstAvailable(  // (optional) use the first focus mode which is supported by device
            FocusModeSelectorsKt. continuousFocusPicture(),
            FocusModeSelectorsKt.autoFocus(),        // in case if continuous focus is not available on device, auto focus will be used
            FocusModeSelectorsKt.fixed()             // if even auto focus is not available - fixed focus mode will be used
    ))
    .flash(SelectorsKt.firstAvailable(      // (optional) similar to how it is done for focus mode, this time for flash
            FlashSelectorsKt.autoRedEye(),
            FlashSelectorsKt.autoFlash(),
            FlashSelectorsKt.torch()
    ))
    .frameProcessor(myFrameProcessor)   // (optional) receives each frame from preview stream
    .logger(LoggersKt.loggers(            // (optional) we want to log camera events in 2 places at once
            LoggersKt.logcat(),           // ... in logcat
            LoggersKt.fileLogger(this)    // ... and to file
    ))
    .build();
```

And start using `yourVariableName`.

Comment: Don't forget to sync Gradle files.

Comment: And what about the instance?

Comment: Please see my EDIT above.

Comment: Thanks for the code. I did some research (using keyword 'java instance' instead of 'android instance') and I think that I got it. The .with is still in red. What do I need to do?

Comment: @Anton, I'm having the same problem with ".with", how did you fix it?

Comment: @Ricardo I do not have access to the code anymore, and I do not remember it. I'm sorry but I hope you will find a solution!

Comment: Everything works fine for me except that I cant get the bitmap using the whenReady() method in Java, the device crashes because the photo bitmap is null. Any help??

Comment: Flash `auto()` and `on()` methods not working in android 10. what to do and how to fix it?